# Taking a value from Promise and returning it instead of console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback

I have an exercise where I have to build some async functions (not using `await/async`, Promises are allowed).
`funcs` need to be a list of those x functions I make.
Each of the function has to receive callback as an argument.
The callback is made with `(err,res)` where err could be either `null` or the statement of error (I don't know how to determine any error there).
Function `together` need to return an Array with the results of those functions, for which the `pred` is fulfilled.

Before I go to `together` function, I have to ask you, how to get into the value of Promise if I don't want to `console.log` it, but I want for example to either `return` it in callback or just put it into a `const`. If I make `res.then(...)` I am only able to `console.log` that result, but am not able to put it into `let result` (because of async probably the result is always returned as 0).

My code:

```
function fun1(value,cb) {
    const promise1 =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(  value * 100), 500)
    })
    return cb(null,promise1)

}
function fun2(value,cb) {
    const promise2 =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(  value * 100), 500)
    })
    return cb(null, promise2)
}

function fun3(value,cb) {
    const promise3 =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(  value * 100), 2000)
    })
    return cb(null, promise3)
}
function callback(err, res) {
    let result = 0;
    res.then(x => {
        if(x>200) {
            console.log(x)
            result = x

        }
        else {
            console.log(err)
            result = err
        }
    })


}
console.log(fun1(1,callback))

//const together = (funcs, pred) => (n) => { ... };
```

Comment: You can't use `async / await` but the thing you're asking is exactly what `async / await` solves.

Comment: If I'm not 100% able to do that exercise without `async/await`. Could you please give me some advices how to make it with using them then?

Comment: Any function that wants to access the value of a promise needs to return a promise itself. There is no other way.

Comment: Then how would I check if for e.g. pred = 5, which would determine that the result of the function needs to be > 5, how would I check if the result of the function is greater than 5, if I'm not able to get into the value which `Promise` returns?

Comment: Why do you even use a promises inside `funX` if you accept a callback? Passing the promise to the callback just seems wrong. Either pass the actual value to the callback *or* return the promise but don't mix both.

Comment: I have to have as one of the argument in funX the callback. The funX need to be asynchronus (but not using async), so I didn’t have any other idea than to do it this way. If I return the promise, my cb is useless then, because I wouldnt refere to it, would I?

Comment: Yep. So don't use promises and just do `setTimeout(() => cb(value * 100), 500)`.

Comment: Thank you, will try!

Comment: I highly suggest [_What are callbacks?_](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) and [_What are the error conventions?_](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/errors/what-are-the-error-conventions/)