# Mixing setTimeout with the callback functions - problem with returning values before the setTimeout ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

according to what I asked yesterday: [Taking a value from Promise and returning it instead of console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712818/taking-a-value-from-promise-and-returning-it-instead-of-console-log)

I still have a problem, because when I try to turn on the list of functions, the `return results` happen before it even gets into the functions. I can't use `async/await`, so that's why I struggle with this exercise.

Is there any way to:

1. If I `console.log(fun1(1000,callback))` it doesn't return anything (undefined), but I would like it to return the value `res`, but not console.logging it, but just to make the callback return it.
2. The idea is to put into `results` those results, that the `pred` accepts, so e.g. greater than 5.
3. I know that the problem is with `setTimeout` probably, but as mentioned in the post I posted yesterday - I can't use `async/await` to fix that problem.

My code:

```
function fun1(value,cb) {
    if ((value * 100) > 400)  {
        setTimeout(() => cb(null, value*100), 1000)
    }
    else {
       setTimeout(() => cb(new Error("error")), 1000)
    }
}
function fun2(value,cb) {
    if ((value * 20) > 50)  {
        setTimeout(() => cb(null, value*20), 2000)
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(() => cb(new Error("error")), 2000)
    }
}

function fun3(value,cb) {
    if ((value -30 ) > 0)  {
        setTimeout(() => cb(null, value-30), 3000)
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(() => cb(new Error("error")), 3000)
    }
}
function callback(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else {
        console.log(res)
        return res
    }


}
console.log(fun1(1000,callback))

const together = (funcs, pred) => (n) => {
    let results = []
    funcs.reduce((prev,curr) => {
        if (curr(n,callback) > pred) {
            results.push(curr(n,callback))
        }

    }, 0)
    return results
};

console.log(together([fun1,fun2,fun3], 5)(10))
```

Comment: I have a question, if I remove those timeouts, would it still be asynchronic function?

Comment: how about my question - if I remove those timeouts, would it still be asynchronic function? I can't really understand what that asynchronic mean many times.

Comment: Did you asked about `setTimeout` ?,  `setTimeout` is like a timer, it execute a unit (callback) later,

Comment: I meant - If I remove setTimeout, and leave only return cb(....), would it still be (fun1) an async function or not?

Comment: No!, Why would that be?

Comment: I was according to what one guy said sent me yesterday: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/
there isn't any timeout and they say it was an async function.

Comment: This is true, In JavaScript we handle async operation in 3 ways, **1st** Old school callback, **2nd** chain callback (Promise) **3rd** Sync like (async/await), And I suggest you to switch `async/await`, It will simplify your code up to 10x,

Comment: I actually had a problem do this exercise using Promise. You could check the yesterday's article I sent and see, that I wasn't able to do it. Could I use promise here somehow?

Comment: in your code, without `setTimeout` there is no async stuff, be it does not mean that you can only use callback for doing asynchronous stuff only, you can also use callback to a sync function also

Comment: in this exercise the functions had to be async, so I have to fix it somehow, but  the functions have to have (value,cb) as arguments.

Comment: Ok, so what is your expected output would be from `together` ?

Comment: The array of the results, that did not throw error and the pred accepts, so in this case the results that are > 5. So in this case it would be the Array of [1000,200]

Answer (score 1):

In past people afraid to write async code because of callback, As so I, So I will use promise,

So that you need to return a `Promise` object from your function like:

```js
function fun1(value) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        if ((value * 100) > 400)
            setTimeout(() => res(value * 100), 1000)
        else
            setTimeout(() => rej(new Error("error")), 1000)
    });
}
```

Instead of warping a `Promise` object, I took deferent approach, I wrote a utility function (`callFuture`) that call `cl` and return a `Promise` object for us.

```js
function callFuture(fn, value, cl) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fn(value, (...v) => {
            let result = cl(...v);
            if (result instanceof Error)
                rej(result)
            else
                res(result)
        })
    });
}

function fun1(value, cb) {
    if ((value * 100) > 400)
        setTimeout(() => cb(null, value * 100), 1000)
    else
        setTimeout(() => cb(new Error("error")), 1000)
}
function fun2(value, cb) {
    if ((value * 20) > 50)
        setTimeout(() => cb(null, value * 20), 2000)
    else
        setTimeout(() => cb(new Error("error")), 2000)
}

function fun3(value, cb) {
    if ((value - 30) > 0)
        setTimeout(() => cb(null, value - 30), 3000)
    else
        setTimeout(() => cb(new Error("error")), 3000)
}

function callback(err, res) {
    return err ? err : res
}

callFuture(fun1, 100, callback)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log)

async function together(funcs, pred, n) {
    let results = [];
    for (const fn of funcs) {
        try {
            let v = await callFuture(fn, n, callback);
            if (v > pred)
                results.push(v);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`error`)
        }
    }
    return results;
}

together([fun1, fun2, fun3], 5, 10).then(console.log)
```

You can think `await callFuture(fn, n, callback)` is like synchronous (this is not true), There is no need to do anything to handle async stuff, it will return result or throw error (much like a sync function), Any you can handle error with `try/catch` as like you do in a sync function...

Comment: thank you very much! could you tell me what `(...v)` means?

Comment: its es6 `rest` operator, it will wrap all `arg` as array, like where `v` is `[err, res]`

Answer (score 0):

This works when use the callback function

**Your Example Include the callback after timeout**:

```js
 function fun1(value, calculate, callback) {
  if (value * 100 > 400) {
     setTimeout(() => {
      let result = calculate(null, value * 100);
      callback(result)
    }, 1000);
  } else {
     setTimeout(() => cb(new Error("error")), 1000);
  }
}

function calculate(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  }
}

fun1(1000, calculate, function(result) {
  console.log(`this is the result in the callback after timeout ${result}`)
});
```

Comment: no, it does not work, because it still doesn't return anything, it console-logs it. You did not change anything :( 
It has to return something, because the results have to go into reduce, and curr(n,callback) has to be the result that callback returns, as for now, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Ok I understood. So I edited the code to add a callback function afteer the timeout finish. So When timeout has finished the will trigger the callback function with the values from the calculate. That was your old cb function